# How to make part of circle at background color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-container

Like below

[image]

I used BoxDecoration in Container Widget.
But I have not created

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
      bottom: Radius.circular(100),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I can't imagine UI in Flutter.
Hope your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean this? Part of the circle in the background and a widget in the foreground?

Source code:

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 100,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(100)),
  ),
  child: const Center(child: Text("Hey!")),
),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :
You can use Custom Painter. For example, you can check this article on it by Flutter Developers
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Option 2 :
You can use Stack to add an Image in the Background as below

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(Res.background), // Your background goes here
            .... Other Widgets.....


          ],
        )
```